# JQuery Framework for Webapp

Tags: jquery

i'm currently looking at developing a webapp using jQuery. I do know the concepts of the library but I would like to easily do ajax requests, add calendars and other ui stuff without writing to much code.

Can anyone here point me to a framework that can help me out?

Comment: uhm, what about jQuery + jQuery UI ?

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but is it any good? I've seen backbone and react too.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through your post, there are a lot of good libraries out there to help you on your quest to write code efficiently. For a decent calendar library check out [Full Calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/).

Building a slick web-apps are a lot of fun, and I'm not sure if you ever checked out [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) they allow data-binding which should help you write less code, and be more efficient with what you do write.

Good luck with your web app!

Comment: Thank you so much, great answer, I will have a look at these!